# Phonegap : Angular Controller does not work in new window

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova

I'm working on a project based on `PhoneGap 3.5` and `Angular.js`. I try to use Angular New Window InAppBrowser with the following controller :

```
var gWindow;
window.loadWindow = function(website) {
    gWindow = window.open(website, '_blank', 'location=no');
    gWindow.addEventListener('loadstart', function(event) { 
        //alert('start: ' + event.url); 
    });
    gWindow.addEventListener('loadstop', fLoadStop);
    gWindow.addEventListener('loaderror', function(event) { 
        //alert('error: ' + event.message); 
    });
    gWindow.addEventListener('exit', fExit);
}
window.fLoadStop = function(event) {
    var url = event.url;
    var filename = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
    if(filename == "closeinappbrowser.html"){
        gWindow.close();
    }
}
window.fExit = function(event) {
    gWindow.removeEventListener('loadstop', fLoadStop);
    gWindow.removeEventListener('exit', fExit);
}
```

But i don't know why controller below not work in new window appbrowser but work in dekstop browser

```
newsappblank = angular.module("newsappblank", ["ngRoute", "newsControllersblank", "newsServices", "ngSanitize", "ui.bootstrap", "slugifier", "bn-lazy"]);

newsappblank.config([
    "$routeProvider", function($routeProvider) {
      return $routeProvider.when("/news/:newsId", {
        templateUrl: "partials/news-detail.html",
        controller: "NewsDetailCtrl"
      }).otherwise({
        redirectTo: "../closeinappbrowser.html"
      });
    }
  ]);

newsControllersblank = angular.module("newsControllersblank", []);
    newsControllersblank.controller("NewsDetailCtrl", [
        "$scope", "$rootScope", "$location", "$anchorScroll", "$http", "$routeParams", function($scope, $rootScope, $location, $anchorScroll, $http, $routeParams) {
          $rootScope.middlebar = true;
          $rootScope.loadbar = false;
          alert(1);
          return $scope.go = function(path) {
            if (path !== '/news/') {
              $location.path(path);
              $location.hash("top");
              return $anchorScroll();
            }
          };
        }
      ]);
```

Comment: Is it possible you are not loading Angular itself in the app browser? Can you give more information? Is there a specific error or is it just not doing anything? does it replace text, etc?

Comment: the display is blank , ajax is work but can't load template

Comment: Maybe the problem is Phonegap, which library is included? How do you test the app in your browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ' ve got the problem , Phonegap Inapp Browser Not Support Jquery Load to Load Angular Template , so the solution is i write the html template to a variable and call it .

Comment: Would you explain a little more?